# Vue 3, render function

Tags: vue.js

Каким образом компонент может получить доступ к router-link, который рендерится с помощью приведенного ниже кода:

```html
h(MapPopupInfo, {
        regionStat: this.regionStat,
        regionName,
        regionId,
      });
```

Код компонента:

```html
<template>
  <div class="interactive__block" id="MapPopupInfo">
    <div class="interactive__body">
      <div class="interactive__header">
        <h4>{{ regionName }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="interactive__row">
        <div
          class="interactive__line"
          :key="statPart.code"
          v-for="statPart in regionStat"
        >
          <p>{{ statPart.title }}</p>
          <span>{{ statPart.value }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="interactive__link">
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="$router.history.push(`cabinet/organizations/${regionId}`)"
          >Подробная статистике по региону</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "map-popup-info",
  props: {
    regionStat: Object,
    regionId: Number,
    regionName: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Что именно подразумевается под _"получить доступ к router-link"_? Если нужно использовать компонент `router-link` в компоненте `map-popup-info`, то его можно подключить через `import` и добавить в свойство объявления компонента `components`. Если нужно получить доступ к такому компоненту как к элементу, то тут сложно ответить т.к. такого элемента в коде не нахожу.

Comment: В компоненте map-popup-info вместо тега <a><a/> нужно использовать router-link. При импорте этого компонента, и добавления его в свойство components, выдаёт следующее:
vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2057 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')

Comment: Возможно, стоит поискать решение именно этой проблемы? Можете написать какие именно версии `vue` и `vue-router` у вас заблокированы в менеджере пакетов?

Comment: "vue": "^3.2.26",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"

Comment: Попробовал [тут (на codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-firefly-qc0no?file=/src/components/MapPopupInfo.vue) повторить ошибку на основании вашего кода. Ошибки не произошло. Возможно ошибка кроется в самих роутах или их компонентах?